# Manually configure Jackson Module for Spring WebTestClient

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jackson, geojson, spring-webflux

## Prerequisites

- Spring Boot: `2.0.3.RELEASE`
- Spring REST Docs: `2.0.1.RELEASE`
- Spring Auto REST Docs: `2.0.2-SNAPSHOT` - Which is a local build of the [current master](https://github.com/ScaCap/spring-auto-restdocs/tree/431f76ef0e810a1b87df3361414b63ca344e9744).

The GeoJsonModule is configured in the Main Application:

```java
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.geo.GeoJsonModule;

@SpringBootApplication
public class MyApplication {
    [...]
    @Bean
    public GeoJsonModule registerGeoJsonModule() {

        return new GeoJsonModule();
    }
    [...]
}
```

I am using [Spring Auto REST Docs](https://github.com/ScaCap/spring-auto-restdocs) and therefore cannot use the `@AutoConfigure`-Annotation (Or atleast I don't know how).

## Current Implementation

I configure the WebTestClient like so:

```java
WebTestClient
    .bindToApplicationContext(context)
    .configureClient()
    .filter(
        WebTestClientRestDocumentation
            .documentationConfiguration(restDocumentation)
            .snippets()
            .withDefaults(
                WebTestClientInitializer.prepareSnippets(context),
                CliDocumentation.curlRequest(),
                HttpDocumentation.httpRequest(),
                HttpDocumentation.httpResponse(),
                AutoDocumentation.requestFields(),
                AutoDocumentation.responseFields(),
                AutoDocumentation.pathParameters(),
                AutoDocumentation.requestParameters(),
                AutoDocumentation.description(),
                AutoDocumentation.methodAndPath(),
                AutoDocumentation.section()
            )
    )
    .build();
```

However when using the WebTestClient like this I get the following error:

```java
org.springframework.core.codec.CodecException: Type definition error: [simple type, class org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.geo.GeoJsonPoint]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.geo.GeoJsonPoint` (no Creators, like default construct, exist): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)
at [Source: UNKNOWN; line: -1, column: -1] (through reference chain: com.example.MyClass["location"])
```

So I looked around and found, that the [`WebTestClientAutoConfiguration`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/b6f9b46be86c7faa66259893efa93f421f42bf3e/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-test-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/test/autoconfigure/web/reactive/WebTestClientAutoConfiguration.java) and [`SpringBootWebTestClientBuilderCustomizer`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/adf0d616c16ba1d86d74ec83b83087dc2ee9f7ba/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-test-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/test/autoconfigure/web/reactive/SpringBootWebTestClientBuilderCustomizer.java) are [additionally customizing Codecs](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/adf0d616c16ba1d86d74ec83b83087dc2ee9f7ba/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-test-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/test/autoconfigure/web/reactive/SpringBootWebTestClientBuilderCustomizer.java#L65).

Changing the initialization to include the customizers fixes the deserialization issue and it works.

```java
Collection<CodecCustomizer> customizers = context.getBeansOfType(CodecCustomizer.class).values();

SpringBootWebTestClientBuilderCustomizer builderCustomizer = new SpringBootWebTestClientBuilderCustomizer(customizers);
builderCustomizer.customize(builder);
builder.build();
```

However I do not know if this is the correct way of configuring the WebTestClient and if it works entirely or if something is still broken I just did not discover yet.

Somehow I don't think that this is the intended way and I would like to know how the WebTestClient can be configured properly.